# Mongoid has_many relation too slow (never ends) - 40k documents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid, nosql

I have a `Client` and a `Group` models. A client has many groups.

```
class Client
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Paranoia
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field ...

  has_many :groups, dependent: :delete

  ...
end

class Group
  ...

  belongs_to :client
end
```

One client has **40k** groups and when I try `client.groups` it takes too long. I have wait for several minutes and it never ends.

```
MONGODB (14.2ms) humtl_development['groups'].find({:deleted_at=>nil, "client_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('51b37763218c5a19e0000048')})
MONGODB [DEBUG] cursor.refresh() for cursor 48594378191047181
```

I found [this](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/tips.html#relational_associations) in mongoid docs.

Are 40k too much documents? Should I get rid of `has_many` relation and use `embeds_many` instead? The problem is my mongoid version? MongoDB configuration? Any advice is appreciated.

For sure I don't need to display all 40k groups, what I need is `User.where(:group_id.in => client.groups.map(&:id))`.

Thanks so much.

PS:
MongoDB v2.4.3
mongoid v2.7.1
mongo v1.9.2

Comment: You probably don't want to embed with so many documents, cause a document's size is limited.

Comment: Loading 40k documents into memory is going to take awhile no matter what.

Comment: It may be faster to use "pluck" instead of map. This way you are only pulling the id's out of the db instead of each entire doc and then iterating through each in memory.

Comment: `User.where(:group_id.in => client.groups.map(&:id))` is a way to simulate a JOIN in MongoDB, a way that only works with small sets. You'll probably have better luck if you rework your schema to precompute and cache that JOIN, you'll also have to maintain that cache whenever things change and write a sanity checker to periodically check the cache to ensure that it is correct.

Comment: So you want to get all users for a client's groups.  Do you need all users? In this case seems that you would be better with a relational database.

Comment: Where and why you need all that data?  Is it for a report? Or just to have a count of users?

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I'm working on a big project so at this point is impossible to change to a relational DB. `User.where..` is not the only thing that I need to do, there are much more methods that "call" `client.groups` (not only the "JOIN").

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have `client_id` indexed on your document so lookups are fast. then you can use `distinct(:_id)` to get 40K ids in an array. so your final query will look like: `User.where(:group_id.in => client.groups.distinct(:_id))`. That is the most efficient way I can think of to get array of 40K ids. Try that - it might work, but as everyone stated already - it's not webscale ;)

From what I can see, you are trying to get all users for a given client, and your user might be associated to multiple clients through different groups. In order to be able to efficiently look up Users for clients without join (since you dont have join in mongoid), you can use HABTM on users with clients without inverse relation. So I would do following:

```
class Client
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Paranoia
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field ...

  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  has_many :groups, dependent: :delete

  ...
end

class User
  has_and_belongs_to_many :clients
end
```

Then every time you associate user to a group, remember to add group's client to user (`user.clients << client` or `client.users << user`) so they know about each other. Don't worry about duplication since mongoid is using Set so if relation between user and client already exists, its not going to do anything. Then you can look up users from client: `client.users` or lookup users for multiple clients: `User.where(:client_ids.in => client_ids)`

Comment: Thanks. The `client.groups.distinct(:_id)` works :o ... but `User.where....` is still very slow. PS: User belongs to Group.

Comment: add index and it will be fast. also how many users are you expecting? slowness can be from DB or from Ruby. Adding index on foreign keys will remove slowness from DB side